# forall/2 predicate query doesn’t return results

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have the following facts.

```
loves(ami, paul).
loves(lucy, paul).

female(ami).
artist(ami).
female(lucy).
artist(lucy).

canadian(paul).

lovesCanadianArtists(Person) :- forall(canadian(X), loves(Person, X)).
```

When I execute the query in SWI-Prolog:

```
?- lovesCanadianArtists(X).
```

The answer is `true`, and I don't get results.

Someone told me that the issue is the predicate `isLovedByArtists(Person)` is not inversible or invertible. So, I should add a condition on `Person` variable because it is not bound by the `forall\2` predicate. Like:

```
lovesCanadianArtists(Person) :- female(Person), forall(canadian(X), loves(Person, X)).
```

So, my questions are:

- Is this predicate invertibility documented anywhere ? I can't find it.
- For me, the explanation given is wrong, and but I am not sure whether I should get results with my first rule. What's the underlying issue here ?

Comment: Use `foreach` instead of `forall`, to instantiate `Person`.

Comment: Thank you for the info about `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the underlying issue here ?

"*forall/2 does not change any variable bindings. [...] If your intent is to create variable bindings, the forall/2 control structure is inadequate.*" - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=forall2

Perhaps one of foreach, findall, bagof or setof will do what you want, although it's not clear from the plural 'artists' and singular 'Person' exactly what that is; e.g. for a list of all People who love at least one Canadian artist, which may have duplicates if you add more Canadian artists:

```
lovesCanadianArtists(People) :-
    findall(Person, (canadian(X), loves(Person, X)), People).
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Could you explain what's the meaning of "forall/2 does not change any variable bindings."

Comment: Perhaps the name of the predicate isn't ideal. `Person` loves all Canadian artists. That's the intended meaning.

Comment: In your code you want the variable `Person` to be bound to an answer, and `forall` does not do that kind of binding variables to values. I don't know why not.

Comment: Thank you. I upvoted your answer but the argument should be `Person`, and as you noted, gives duplicated results. I appreciate though your insights so much, though.